# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:login\ValidacionUsuario.php

Tags: pdo

me da Fatal error:Call to a member function prepare(). cuando trato de logearme.

no me permite acceder a la pagina **acceso.php** una vez validado debería ir allí.

mi archivo **conectar_bd.php**

```
$host= 'localhost';
$basedatos= 'login';
$usuario= 'root';
$contrasena= '';

try {
$conectar = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$basedatos", $usuario, $contrasena);
print "Conexión exitosa desde PDO!";
}
catch (PDOException $econexion) {
print "¡Error al conectar!: " . $econexion->getMessage() . "";
die();
}
$conectar =null;
```

Mi archivo que permitiría validar **validarUsuario.php**
En la pagina validarUsuario.php me aparece conexión exitosa pero también en me aparece este mensaje de error.

```
require 'conectar_bd.php';

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $errMsg = '';


        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($username == '')
            $errMsg = 'Enter username';
        if($password == '')
            $errMsg = 'Enter password';
        if($errMsg == '') {
            try {
                $stmt = $conectar->prepare('SELECT usuario,password,registro FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :username');
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $username
                    ));
                $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if($data == false){
                    $errMsg = "User $username not found.";
                }
                else {
                    if($password == $data['password']) {

                        $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];

                        header('Location: acceso.php');
                        exit;
                    }
                    else
                        $errMsg = 'Password not match.';
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                $errMsg = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo te diria que es culpa de

```
$conectar =null;
```

ya que al hacer esto vacias la conexion hacia la base de datos 
hise una prueba con un select * a una tabla en local y si la trajo sin esa linea

por si te sirve te pongo el codigo de la prueba:

**Este es de mi modelo.php**

```
<?php 
$host= 'localhost';
$basedatos= 'pruebas';
$usuario= 'root';
$contrasena= '';

try 
{
    $conectar = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$basedatos", $usuario, $contrasena);
    print "Conexión exitosa desde PDO!";
}
catch (PDOException $econexion)
{
    print "¡Error al conectar!: " . $econexion->getMessage() . "";
die();
}
```

?>

**este es de mi controlador:[Modificado x2]**

```
<?php 
require 'modelo.php';
if (isset($_POST['btn_ok'])) 
{
    $nombre_u=$_POST['txt_nom'];
    $edad_u=$_POST['txt_edad'];

    $rows = array();
    $stmt = $conectar->prepare("SELECT * from personas where nombre_pe = :nombre_u ");

    if(!$stmt)
    {
        echo "Error al mostrar";
    }
    else
    {           
        $stmt->execute(array(
                ':nombre_u' => $nombre_u
                ));     
        while ($result = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            $rows[] = $result;
        }
        if ($rows != null) 
        {                       
           if ($rows[0]['edad_pe'] == $edad_u) 
           {
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $respuesta = "<label style='color:red;'>Algun campo podria estar vacio o equivocado</label>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $respuesta = "<label style='color:red;'>Algun campo podria estar vacio o equivocado</label>";
        }
    }
}
  require 'vista.php'
```

?>

Nota: Le hice cambias para hacer algo parecido a lo del login sin embargo use los campos que son nombre y edad para usuario y contraseña pero me funciono asi 
espero que resuelva el otro error.

Nota2: le añadi que imprimiera si no exite el nombre y si esta mal la edad XD $respuesta se imprime en la vista en caso de que los campos esten equivocados o esten vacios.

Comment: Que tal estimado, gracias por tu colaboracion, quitando ese $conectar =null desaparece el error pero a pesar de ello aun no accedo a la pagina acceso.php queda en la pagina validaUsuario.php con el mensaje Conexion exitosa desde PDO! el mismo que esta en conectar_bd.php.

Comment: checa lo que añadi probe a hacer algo parecido al login y asi me funciono :D espero que te sirva si te sale algun error o alguna duda del codigo  lo comentas.

Comment: Estimado Persona_A en la parte final del controlador modificado esta **require 'vista.php'** hize la prueba y llego hasta el mismo mensaje de validaUsuario.php **conexion exitosa desde PDO.** ¿Por tu lado te lleva a un tercer .php después de validado?. En mi caso aun no a pesar de los cambio sugeridos.
Saludos Gracias.